# SQLite query returns two answers

Tags: android, sqlite

I´m writing an android application that receives gps data from a MySQL database, such as gps coordinates, and then tells the shows the user these coordinates on Google maps.

I have a SQLite database that stores the Latitude and Longitude values locally, and my question is how I can retrieve these values in on SQLite query and return the values in to two strings.
This is my take on the problem.

DbAdapter class "Databasehandler":

```
    public Cursor getLatLng(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARCOORD + " WHERE name = " + CAR_KEY_NAME , null);
    }
```

Class "UserFunction":

```
    public String getCoords(Context context, String lat, String lng) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    Cursor cursor = db.getLatLng();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
        lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));
    }
    return lat, lng;
    }
```

It gives me  error when i try to return two values. Anyone that haves any suggestions?
I'm a beginner at android programming and Java in general, so please forgive me if there is an obvious answer to this.

Comment: You could make a custom Coordinates class which would be better design-wise. Or you could just return an array of strings.

Comment: What error do you get. Please edit your question and include the complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of returning String change return type of method to `ArrayList` or String Array to return  more then one value from method as :

```
 public ArrayList<String> getCoords(Context context, String lat, String lng) {
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
 ArrayList<String> locarrlist=new  ArrayList<String>();
Cursor cursor = db.getLatLng();
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
    lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));
    locarrlist.add(lat);
    locarrlist.add(lng);
}
return locarrlist;
}
```

and in other call retrieve these values as :

```
 ArrayList<String> locarrlist=getCoords(context,lat,lng);
 String lat = locarrlist.get(0);
 String lng = locarrlist.get(1);
```

Comment: Many thanks! Is it possible to use "ArrayList<Double>"? The Google maps "LatLng" takes doubles, not strings as arguments `LatLng position = new LatLng(Double, Double)`, or should i convert the strings to double?

Comment: @ErikSoderstrom : yes it is possible because i thing u are string lat and lng in db as String then just it to Double after retrieving from ArrayList